# Slideshow program, why is the last slide showing twice?

Tags: javascript, html

All my images are in the html, and it couldn’t be a simpler program.
I just cannot figure out where the repetition comes from:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imgArray = $("#slides img:first-child");
  var newCaption;
  var nextImg;
  var SlideShow = function() {
    $("#slide").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      if (imgArray.length == 0) {
        imgArray = $("#slides img:first-child");
      } else {
        imgArray = imgArray.next();
      }
      
      nextImg = imgArray.attr("src");
      newCaption = imgArray.attr("alt");
      $("#slide").attr("src", nextImg).fadeIn(1000);
      $("#caption").text(newCaption).show(1000);
    });
  };
  var stop = setInterval(SlideShow, 2000);
  
  $("#slide").click(function() {
    stop = setInterval();
  });
});
```

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: _“It couldn’t be a simpler program”_ — Then it couldn’t be easier to debug. Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). [Rubber Duck Debug](//rubberduckdebugging.com/) your code. Try using the [debugging capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Use tools like [JSHint](//jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately. [Validate your HTML](//html5.validator.nu/).

Comment: What do you think does `stop = setInterval();` do? Are you aware of [`clearInterval`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)?

Comment: I'm sure it's easy for some, but not for me...

Comment: @MarioPelletier You should still [edit] your post and provide a [mre]. `if (imgArray.length == 0)` doesn’t really seem to make any sense. You’re getting `imgArray.next()`, and then do the `src` attribute thing on it. But you’re not checking if `imgArray.next()` exists until _after_ the fadein and fadeout. Maybe you should move the check: `imgArray = imgArray.next(); if(imgArray.length === 0){ imgArray = $("#slides img:first-child"); }`.

Comment: That was exactly it. Thanx for the lesson!

Answer (score 1):

The logic is wrong here:

```js
if (imgArray.length == 0) {
  imgArray = $("#slides img:first-child");
} else {
  imgArray = imgArray.next();
}
```

Imagine, you’re at the *last* `<img>` inside the `id="slides"` element.
Is `imgArray.length == 0`?
Of course not.
You’re at the last one, so `imgArray` contains one element, so its length is `1`.
The `else` part will now get executed and set `imgArray` to the `.next` sibling.
But there is no next sibling, because you just were at the *last* `<img>`.
So now, `imgArray` is an empty jQuery object.
No next element exists.

Then you go ahead and get `.attr("src")` of *nothing*.
Then you go ahead and get `.attr("alt")` of *nothing*.
Both of these result in `undefined` as [documented](https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Then, you `.fadeIn(1000)` the `id="slide"` element, but, weirdly, also set its `src` attribute.
What do you think this does?
An `<img>` cannot contain another `<img>`, so setting the `src` of the container that contains all `<img>`s is meaningless.

And once the `setInterval` is triggered again, the cycle repeats with a `fadeOut`.
And *only now* do you finally check if `imgArray` even exists, after wrongly assuming that it does, setting `src` and `alt`, and doing fade-out animations.
*Only now* do you set `imgArray = $("#slides img:first-child");`.

[Rubber Duck Debug](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) your code.
This means: go through the execution by hand and try to explain each step.
It repeats at the end, you say, so what happens if `imgArray` contains the last `<img>`?
What is the next statement that is executed?
Does it make sense?
Why do you think so?

Use the debugger built into your browser.
You can observe the `imgArray` expression, or the `imgArray.length` expression.
Do these expressions always produce the values you expect?
At which point do they no longer do that?

Use `console.log` debugging.
The single statement `console.log({ imgArray, imgArrayLength: imgArray.length, imgArrayNext: imgArray.next() })` may already answer several questions; you can copy-paste it after any one of your statements.

So move the check:

```js
var SlideShow = function(){
    $("#slide").fadeOut(1000, function(){
      imgArray = imgArray.next();
    
      if (imgArray.length === 0) {
        imgArray = $("#slides img:first-child");
      }

      // Etc.
    });
  };
```

Next problem: `stop = setInterval();`.
`stop` is never used, other than as an assignment target.
Reassigning some variable doesn’t affect previously assigned objects.
It doesn’t stop the interval.
Stopping the inveral is done with [`clearInterval(stop);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval).

Comment: I did and found the problem. Thx!